# Adding Handlebars helpers to scaffolt

Tags: handlebars.js, brunch

How does one go about adding Handlebars helpers to the `scaffolt` processing that comes with `brunch`? I'd like to do some more interesting conditional statements in my scaffolt templates but need to understand this process.

Oh, also, does anyone have any smart helpers that look at a name and deduce if the name indicates being singular or plural?